# Twig variable inside other twig variable?

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig

So, I've been working on a website for a reggae backing band and on the 'booking' page I have a form. After submitting the form I first (ofcourse) check if all required fields are filled in, if something else went wrong or if it succeeded.

But, I have a couple of language files (nl, de, fr and en). On the HTML page I first check if an error was set inside the PHP and if there is an error, I want to output it in the right language.

So in case of an error, the HTML would have to look like this

`{{ lang.booking.{{ form_error }} }}`

because I am sending the error type in the PHP as well, but this doesn't seem to be possible (obviously).

Can someone help me out or tell me how to get around this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [attribute](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/functions/attribute.html) function to access a dynamic attribute of a variable.

```
{{ attribute(lang.booking, form_error) }}
```

Comment: Thank you!! Didn't know this function until now, seems handy for a lot of other things as well. Helped me out!

Answer (score 0):

You can use translation on constraint messages as you can learn in this article: http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/translations.html